# Function specialisation / overloading rules example

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, template-specialization, overload-resolution

I understand you can't partially specialise a function template, I also understand typical function overloading.

Where I need help is in grokking the difference between the below 4 foo() functions. I expect a few of them are different syntax for exactly the same thing?

Could somebody more knowledgeable explain for each function what exactly is happening with regards to is it a template specialisation or overload, and how does the c++ compiler determine what to invoke?

```
//(1)
template<typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
    cout << "template<T> foo(T) " << endl;
}

//(2)
template<>
void foo<int*>(int* l)
{
    cout << "template<> foo<int*>(int*) " << endl;
}

//(3)
template<typename T>
void foo(T* l)
{
    cout << "template<T> foo(T*) " << endl;
}

//(4)
void foo(int* l)
{
    cout << "normal overload foo(int*) " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    foo(x);
    foo(&x);
    return 0;
}
```

Program Output:

```
template<T> foo(T)
normal overload foo(int*)
```

Comment: @Rakete1111 you're right. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through the first call, `foo(x)`.

`int` can't be written as a pointer, unable to deduce parameter, next

```
void foo(int* l);
```

Can't convert `int` to `int*` implicitly, next

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T t);
```

That seems like a good match, like remember it as 2). Next

```
template<>
void foo<int*>(int* l);
```

Can't convert `int` to `int*` implicitly, next

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T* l)
```

So, the only possible match is 2), and so `template<T> foo(T)` is the output.

---

Second call, `foo(&x)`.

```
void foo(int* l);
```

A non-template function which matches perfectly the type of `x`. Let's remember this one.

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T t);
```

Good match! But the previous one is still better, next

```
template<>
void foo<int*>(int* l);
```

Oh, a specialization of the previous template which exactly matches the type, that's better, but 1) is still the better match. Next

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T* l)
```

Better than a specialization, a template without, but doesn't beat the non-template one.

And so, in the end, the non-template function is called. Non-templates are *always* better than templates.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that overload resolution only selects a base template, so 2) can't be chosen before overload resolution. http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: @VS Do you mean that the base template overload never gets selected because there is the specialization

Comment: "Only after it's been decided which base template is going to be selected, and that choice is locked in, will the compiler look around to see if there happens to be a suitable specialization of that template available, and if so that specialization will get used." So, i mean that template specialization is looked AFTER overload.

Comment: @VS Ah, I see what you mean. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: In the absence of function(4), why is function(3) given precedence over function(2). Note I numbered the functions above.

Comment: @Jordan non-specialized templates are better matches than specialized ones

Comment: @Rakete1111 Am I correct in saying function(3) is trying to be a partial specialisation. But due to that not being allowed for functions, it is actually an overload? If so, is there a difference between a function overload and a template function overload?

Comment: @Jordan function(3) is not a partial specialization.

Answer (score 5):

Explanations in comments:

```
// the 1st primary function template, overloaded function template
template<typename T>
void foo(T t)

// full template specialization of the 1st function template with T = int*
template<>
void foo<int*>(int* l)

// the 2nd primary function template, overloaded function template
template<typename T>
void foo(T* l)

// non-template function, overloaded function
void foo(int* l)

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    foo(x);  // only match the 1st function template; the others take pointer as parameter
    foo(&x); // call the non-template function, which is prior to templates in overload resolution
    return 0;
}
```

See more details about [overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function) and [explicit (full) template specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

Answer (score 0):

Resolution of `foo(x)` is easy to spot, as there are no candidate functions other than `template<typename T> void foo(T t)`.

So our problem reduces to : **Why `void foo(int* l)` for `foo(&x)` call?**

1. To call the template method `template<> void foo<int*>(int* l)`
   , you need to call `foo<int*>(&x)`
2. `template<typename T> void foo(T* l)` by calling `foo<int>(&x)`
3. `template<typename T> void foo(T t)`  by calling `foo<int*>(&x)`

As you can see, calling `foo(&x)` doesn't matches with any of the above mentioned three styles of calling with explicit templates.

Note that in the absence of specialised function `void foo(int* l)`, function call `foo<int*>(&x)` would be resolved by a specialised *template-function* `template<> void foo<int*>(int* l)` beating a non-specialised *template-function*  `template<typename T> void foo(T t)`

Comment: In the absence of specialized function `void foo(int* l)`, `template<typename T> void foo(T* l)` will be called for `foo(&x)` call.

Answer (score 0):

when trying to determine what function is called when overloading, the rule is: always find the function that requires the least optimization to be used.

when foo() is called with int, the only function that can be used is the first, since you can't convert int to int*.

when using it with int*:
function 4 can be used without any optimization.
function 3 needs to change T->int in order to run.
function 1 needs to change T to pointer-type, and determine that T points to int.
function 2 is a specialization of function 1

so function 4 can be used immediately, function 2 needs to update template type, and functions 1,2 needs to update template type, and object type.
so they are called in that order: 4 then 3 then 2 then 1